# after group by in LINQ how to get to nested values using select

Tags: linq, select, group-by, igrouping

http://img51.imageshack.us/i/linqquestion.png/

Everything is in the picture.

I just want to get to one of the highlighted values, for example **size**.

code from picture :

```
        var queryGroupDuplicates = from dlc in listDLC
                                   from song in dlc.songs
                                   group dlc by song.shortname into duplicates
                                   where duplicates.Count() > 1
                                   select duplicates;
        queryGroupDuplicates.Dump();
```

Comment: Please paste your code as part of the question - that will help out anyone trying to answer your question not having to type it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var queryGroupDuplicates = from dlc in listDLC
                           from song in dlc.songs
                           group dlc by song.shortname into duplicates
                           where duplicates.Count() > 1
                           select new
                           {
                           duplicatName = duplicates.Key,
                           DLCfiles = from DLCfile in duplicates
                                      select new {DLCfileName = DLCfile.fileName, packName = DLCfile.packName}
                           };
```

This code produces what's in the picture below:
http://img846.imageshack.us/i/linqanswer.png/

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311041.aspx) - i got idea after seeing this, but thanks for your fast response anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
queryGroupDuplicates.First().First().size
```

Comment: nice, had no idea i could do it like that

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to select those fields from *any* one of the items in the group?  Well your picture shows the contents of what in the groups, so pick one of the items in the group and select the fields you want (let's pick the first one's values).

```
var queryGroupDuplicates =
    from dlc in listDLC
    from song in dlc.songs
    group dlc by song.shortname into duplicates
    where duplicates.Count() > 1
    let someItem = duplicates.First()
    select new
    {
        someItem.fileName,
        someItem.gameID,
        someItem.size,
        someItem.errorsDLC,
        someItem.packName,
    };
```